# Spring Integration gateway threads released or not

Tags: spring-integration

```
<gateway id="testService" service-interface="org.example.TestService"
         default-request-channel="requestChannel"/>

public interface TestService {
     void placeOrder(Order order);
 }

<int:router input-channel="requestchannel" expression="payload.name">
    <int:mapping value="foo" channel="channel_one" />
    ....
</int:router>

<int:chain input-channel="channel_one" output-channel="channel_default" >
        <int:gateway request-channel="chainC" error-channel="errChannel"/>
    <int:filter expression="headers['Release'] != null" discard-channel="nullChannel"/>
</int:chain>
```

There are two paths in this chain - success path moving to channel_default and error path moving to null channel.

Can this gateway cause a memory leak. How do I check that? Is there any way to ensure that the threads initiated for handling gateway requests are released after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the flow downstream of channel `chainC` might not return a reply, you need to set the `reply-timeout` to release the thread which will otherwise hang waiting for a reply that will never come.

As long as you have no async handoffs in that subflow, it is safe to set `reply-timeout="0"`, because, in that case, the timer doesn't start until the subflow completes.

If `chainC` always returns a result, or exception, there is no possibility of a memory leak with that configuration.

Comment: BTW, it is customary, here, to accept (and possibly upvote) answers to questions that solved your problem - I see you are using the solution I suggested to your other question.

Comment: Thanks Gary for letting me know, I am new to this forum.

Comment: Reply-timeout is the time the thread will wait for a reply from the chain, after which it will be released. Am I correct? Reply-timeout=0 means it will keep waiting for a response and never timeout and hence will not be release incase there is no response.

Comment: No; "0" means don't wait at all (after the thread returns to the gateway). By default, it waits indefinitely (-1).

Comment: what happens in case of async-subflows, no timer would start as subflow doesn't returns?

Comment: The timer starts immediately after the async handoff. i.e. when the thread returns to the gateway awaiting a reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91611/discussion-between-ruchi-ahuja-and-gary-russell).

Comment: Suppose the placeOrder method returns a Future object. Now if the message is dropped by filter, I think the test gateway will wait indefinitely. Am I correct?

Comment: If a filter is downstream of a gateway then, yes, you'll need a reply-timeout.